# Delete certain array in a multidimensional array if meets a specific criterion. (franklin theme)

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, duplicates

What I am trying to do is to check for duplicates in certain value of a multidimensional array and then to delete the nested array that has the duplicate. I have tried this.

```
$backerarr = $campaign->backers();
$unique = array();

for($i=0; $i<count($backerarr); $i++){
    foreach($backerarr[$i] as $key=>$value){
        if(in_array($value['post_author'], $unique)){
            unset($backerarr[$i]);
        } else {
            $unique[]=$value['post_author'];
        }
    }
}
```

As you may understand I use the franklin theme and I want the backers widget to show a person that have backed 3 times for example only one and not three.

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> object(WP_Post)#495 (24) { 
        ["ID"]=> int(824) 
        ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2014-07-27 14:56:29" 
        ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-07-27 14:56:29" 
        ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["post_title"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" 
        ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed" 
        ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open" 
        ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["post_name"]=> string(3) "824" 
        ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2014-07-27 14:56:29" 
        ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-07-27 14:56:29" 
        ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["post_parent"]=> int(728) 
        ["guid"]=> string(64) "" 
        ["menu_order"]=> int(0) 
        ["post_type"]=> string(7) "edd_log" 
        ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" 
}......
```

The above is part of the array I have to manipulate, after the manipulation only one `$backerarr[i]` should exist with the same `post_author` nested.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535002/remove-duplicate-keys-from-multidimensional-array/4535060#4535060

Comment: can you also post structure of your array as well as required output??