# Simplifying the array by removing same key values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key, key-value

I have a Array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [vendor_id] => 2
            [vendor_total_order] => 80
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [vendor_id] => 2
            [vendor_total_order] => 100
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [vendor_id] => 1
            [vendor_total_order] => 150
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [vendor_id] => 3
            [vendor_total_order] => 80
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [vendor_id] => 5
            [vendor_total_order] => 150
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [vendor_id] => 1
            [vendor_total_order] => 110
        )

)
```

I want to simplify this array in such a way that if the 'vendor_id' are same for two values there there accumulated/summed value should be assigned to 'vendor_total_order' to that 'vendor_id'(basically we are removing values which are having same vendor_id with the total value of duplicates).

So when i provide the above array as input the output should look like as follow

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [vendor_id] => 2
            [vendor_total_order] => 180
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [vendor_id] => 1
            [vendor_total_order] => 260
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [vendor_id] => 3
            [vendor_total_order] => 80
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [vendor_id] => 5
            [vendor_total_order] => 150
        )

)
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535002/remove-duplicate-keys-from-multidimensional-array see this

Comment: @static variable, i have seen the link. can you help me understand how that solution will help me to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to group them using a foreach. Example:

```
$total = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if(!isset($total[$value['vendor_id']])) {
        $total[$value['vendor_id']] = array('vendor_id' => $value['vendor_id'], 'vendor_total_order' => 0);
    }
    $total[$value['vendor_id']]['vendor_total_order'] += $value['vendor_total_order'];
}

$total = array_values($total); // simple reindex
echo '<pre>';
print_r($total);
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/pZYvuk)

Comment: Many Many thanks to you Mr.Ghost it worked like awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to write a custom script that does the following:

1. Creates an empty new "result" array
2. Iterates over the current array and for each item:
3. If the item doesn't exist in result, insert it, otherwise update the total_value value as the sum of it's current value and the new item.
4. Save the result array

Comment: Looks like this should work for my problem, let me try.